# Авто: насколько допустимо?

Tags: стилистика

Речь об официальных текстах.
Как известно, зачастую длинное слово "автомобиль" сокращают до более короткого "авто" (с ударением на О). В художественной литературе это, как мне кажется, вполне допустимо. Но насколько допустимо такое слово в деловых текстах. Например, в описании документов, которые необходимо получать на автомобиль для ввоза его в страну?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

В деловой речи, где требуется строго-научный стиль,где важна точность высказывания, употребление слово "авто" неприемлемо. Оно имеет разговорный оттенок. См.:напр.: [Большой толковый словарь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/bts/)

Answer (score 3):

АВТО, неизм.; ср. Разг. =Автомобиль.

В деловых бумагах это слово с  пометкой "разг." вряд ли допустимо, а во всех остальных случаях (публицистика, реклама, художественные тексты) используется уже очень давно:

"Cars-City" – автосалон в Москве, купить автомобиль в кредит, цены на авто.

"В последний раз я видел вас так близко, в пролёте улицы вас мчал авто..."

Наши альберики, карлики, царствующие над обманутым гигантом, проносятся в сверкающих авто (С. Д. Кржижановский).

Характерно, что в рейтинге двадцати самых продаваемых в США авто первые два места заняли тяжелые пикапы.